# Concerns about continuity and differentiability in higher dimensions

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

I have two concerns about continuity and differentiability. 
What i thought is that a given function $f$ is in $0$ differentiable when $f'$ is continuous in $0$. I guess its true.

So based on this i work on the following task:

Given $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x,y) = (x^2+y^2)\text{sin}(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}})$ for $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$ and $f(0,0) = 0$

Show that $f$ is differentiable in $(0,0)$. What i did is showing that $\partial_x f(0,0) = 0 = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \partial_x f(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})$ and $\partial_y f(0,0) = 0 = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \partial_y f(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})$

That would mean that $\dot f$ is continuous in $(0,0)$ and for me that would mean that $f$ is differentiable in $(0,0)$ right? If this is false then how do i show that $f$ is differentiable in $(0,0)$?

The whole thing gets messy for me when the next task for me is to show that the partial derivatives of $f$ are not continuos in $(0,0)$. How does this fit together?

Comment: Try polar coordinates.

Comment: What do you mean with that?

Comment: Let $x=r\cos(t)$ and $y=r\sin(t)$.

Answer (score 0):

We have that $$f_y(0,0)=\lim_{h \longrightarrow 0} \frac{f(0,h)-f(0,0)}{h}=0$$ $$f_x(0,0)=\lim_{h \longrightarrow 0} \frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}=0$$

Now from definition of differentiability remember that $f$ is differentiable at $a=(0,0)$ if: $$\lim_{(h_1,h_2) \longrightarrow (0,0)} \frac{|f((0,0)+(h_1,h_2))-f(0,0)- <\nabla f(0,0),(h_1,h_2)>|}{||(h_1,h_2)||}=0$$

where $<(x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)>=x_1y_1+x_2y_2$ (the inner product in $\mathbb{R}^2$) and $||(h_1,h_2)||= \sqrt{h_1^2+h_2^2}$

We have that $$\lim_{(h_1,h_2) \longrightarrow (0,0)} \frac{|f((0,0)+(h_1,h_2))-f(0,0)- <\nabla f(0,0),(h_1,h_2)>|}{||(h_1,h_2)||}=\lim_{(h_1,h_2) \longrightarrow (0,0)} \frac{|(h_1^2+h_2^2) sin(\frac{1}{\sqrt{h_1^2+h_2^2}})|}{\sqrt{h_1^2+h_2^2}}= \lim_{(h_1,h_2) \longrightarrow (0,0)} (\sqrt{h_1^2+h_2^2})|sin(\frac{1}{\sqrt{h_1^2+h_2^2}})|=0$$

Thus $f$ is differentable at $(0,0)$